# How to Post Uploaded File on a separate button instead of Auto Upload in Kendo Angular Upload

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular5, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-upload

I am using kendo-ui-angular upload. It has auto upload functionality and even if we set auto-upload:false, it generates a upload button. But i have Form submit button from which i need to upload the file not at the time of upload.

```
<kendo-upload required
                        name="expertUpload" #expertUpload="ngModel"
                        [multiple]="false"
                        [saveUrl]="saveUrl"
                        [removeUrl]="uploadRemoveUrl"
                        (remove)="removeEventHandler($event)"
                        [restrictions]="fileRestrictions"
                        (success)="successEventHandler($event)"
                        [(ngModel)]="myFiles">
</kendo-upload>
```

Can i use [(ngModel)]="myFiles" in my case, while making a http POST call. If yes, what would be the WepAPI Parameter Datatype for it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that with this control. I use upload event to call my custom method to build custom data in to a fromdata object and post to service.

```
(upload)="uploadEventHandler($event)"

uploadEventHandler(e: UploadEvent) {
for (const file of e.files) {
//your code to handle fileinfo build formdata
}
//post code
}
```

I do no operation on saveUrl and removeUrl letting it to Uploadinterceptor. but I need to handle this better for progress bar, my code is still work in progress.